# Scala class constructor, how can I get the names and types of the constructor?

Tags: scala

I have a Scala class as follows:

```
class Test(val one: String, val two: Int) {}
```

How can I find the names of the constructor parameters and the types of the parameters in code?

Answer (score 2):

You can see how to use reflection in Scala (2.10 and above) in the [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html). This explains how to instantiate reflected classes or get the types of the parameters.

About the parameter names, I don't think they are kept after the compilation.

Comment: I see this answer on how to retrieve the parameters from a method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472854/scala-reflection-on-function-parameter-names   ... and this answer covers how to get the constructor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755735/calling-a-constructor-through-reflection-in-scala-2-10

Comment: Thanks Augusto and sdanzig, I just found a duplicate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737968/how-do-i-obtain-ctor-argument-types-via-reflection-in-scala-2-10-1 . So I can get the types and names of the constructor arguments.